# How to delete a registry value in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, registry

How does one delete a registry value in MSBuild 4.0, without deleting the key?

I have tried the [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/), but the [Registry class](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/9c8ecf24-3d8d-2b2d-e986-3e026dda95fe.htm) appears to be missing a method for deleting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use Exec and call command reg delete HKLM\Software\Test /v Testvalue

```
<Exec Command="echo Y|reg delete HKLM\Software\Test /v TestValue" />
```

Comment: In my particular case <Exec/> is not a viable solution because of local security policy. I have resigned myself to having to develop an enhancement the MSBuild Extension Pack. I have offered by source code as a contribution to the MSbuild Extension Pack FOSS project.